# firestore rules not working even though test said they did

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

problem:
when i use the firestore request emulator, it works how i want but when i test it through my app, it lets me make create requests even though i am not authenticated.
note i am using react, easy peasy state managment & firebase spark plan.

**code**:

- **rules**

  ```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /{document=**} {
          allow write: if request.auth != null;
          allow read;
        }
      }
    }
  ```

**submitting to database:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this._db = firebase.firestore();
      this._db
        .collection("txts")
        .limit(50)
        .orderBy("timeMade", "asc")
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          this.setState({ messages: [] });
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            this.setState({
              messages: [...this.state.messages, doc.data().txt],
            });
          });
        });
    } catch (err) {
      alert("Must sign in first!");
    }
  }
  uploadData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.m.trim()) {
      this._db.collection("txts").add({
        txt: this.state.m,
        timeMade: Date.now(),
      });
      this.setState({ m: "" });
    }
  };
```

**things i have tried:**

- i have waited 1 minute (as it said to wait up to 1 minute)
- copied pasted rules from medium post that did what i wanted (still didn't work)

Comment: Security rules on their own do nothing. Please edit your question to include the code that you use in your app and that doesn't work. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen changed it please can you help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `allow read;` without any condition in your rules is equivalent to `allow read: if true;`, so it allows anyone to read all data.

If you want to prevent anyone from reading the data, that'd be:

```
allow read: if false;
```

If you only want authenticated users to reading data, that'd be:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null;
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is hard to help with. But it's fairly simple: with the above rules an unauthenticated write from a non-administrative (so one that does not use an Admin SDK) **will** be rejected. If your write is allowed, you are either authenticated, an administrative user, or writing to a project with different rules. I recommend trying to eliminate these options one by one. For example: `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)` just before the read/write will show you whether the user is signed in\.

Comment: thank you so so much! i thought i wasn't authenticated but when i tried it in incognito and it worked perfectly!!!!